# SSL connection hangs - Java

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, cxf

I have a CXF web services server running with embedded jetty.
A client connects and send several successful requests to the server.
After 5-10 seconds suddenly the client hangs.
The client / server reuse the same connection for all requests.
After running the server with -Djavax.net.debug=all I've noticed the following message before the connection hangs.

```
Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeInternal(true)
Keep-Alive-Timer, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Keep-Alive-Timer, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 22
```

Any idea what should be fixed to disable this Keep-Alive-Timer to close the connection?

Comment: After debugging the KeepAliveCache class, I found out that these messages were related to a HTTP client opened in the server to another server and not related to the client which is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to cxf 3.1.0 the problem disappeared.

Comment: We're having the exact same issue, but we upgraded from CXF 2.7.10 to 3.1.5 (and related dependencies) yet still see the problem. I know this was a year ago, but did you do anything else as well?

Comment: To be clear, we are seeing hangs - we are seeing the same as you posted [to the jetty newsgroup](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg05728.html). We agree that the Keep-Alive messages are from unrelated outbound connections. But still, occasionally an inbound connection will hang until it times out. We are still debugging that issue, and any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: In my case upgrading did the trick. You might try moving to 3.1.0 if that's easy and see if it still happens. @Ricket